# Caml Query Datetime

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

How can I query my custom list and only show items if the field `dateField`, is in today's month?

Here is my query so far:

```
<Query>
 <Where>
  <Or>
<Eq>
  <FieldRef Name="dateField"></FieldRef>
  <Value Type="Datetime"> <Month /> </Value>
</Eq>
<IsNotNull>
  <FieldRef Name="dateField"></FieldRef>
</IsNotNull>
 </Or>
</Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 7):

Date range would be better:

```
   <Where>  <And>
     <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name='DateField2BeFiltered' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'>2014-08-01T12:00:00Z</Value>
     </Geq>
     <Lt>
        <FieldRef Name='HmniaEggrafou' />
        <Value Type='DateField2BeFiltered'>2014-09-01T12:00:00Z</Value>
     </Lt>
   </And>  </Where>
```

There's a great tool named http://www.camldesigner.com that helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

have you tried combining CAML with JavaScript?

Get the current month:

JS:

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var myDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = monthNames[myDate.getMonth()];
```

CAML:

```
 <Query>
 <Where>
 <Or>
 <Eq>
 <FieldRef Name="dateField"></FieldRef>
 <Value Type="Datetime"> <Month />+ currentMonth + </Value>
 </Eq>
 <IsNotNull>
 <FieldRef Name="dateField"></FieldRef>
 </IsNotNull>
 </Or>
 </Where>
 </Query>
```