# How to calculate first day of the current month?

Tags: date

SharePoint 2010; Workflow;

Need to create a date variable which should be populated with the first day of the current month. Is it possible?

I tried calculate date (no luck) because you have to hard code input the day (minus today's day and then plus 1 day) to current date.

I am running out of option.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

```
1. Build string:fn-Trim(fn-FormatDate({Common:CurrentDate},"yyyy")-01-fn-FormatDate({Common:CurrentDate},"MM")T12:00:00Z)
2. Convert string to DateTime (it worked this time).

Credit goes to XristosK: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114374/caml-query-datetime
```